# Android program stopped working as soon as button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android app making, but I'm able to understand java. The program which I'm making, should return relative frequency of characters that are in the text that person will write in the program (input text is meant to be written in EditText field with id inputText, and as soon as person will click button with id continueButton, onClick the program should continue with onClickFindRelevancy method). The code seems fine to me, but the problem is still occuring. I am able to input the text, but as soon as I click the button, then the app stops working and I just can't figure out what is wrong... What do I need to change in code (what is wrong), for the program to do what is intended?

I really tried to find a solution to my problem, but didn't find something like I have (just seeing the code snippets that someone else had problems with), so I hope that this topic won't be closed, because I tried and really didn't find the solution. Have been trying for some time now.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.<theprogrammnameihave>;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void  onClickFindRelevancy(View view)
    {
        EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        String input = inputText.getText().toString();
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        Map<Character, Float> k = new TreeMap<Character, Float>();
        for (char b : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (k.containsKey(b)) {
                k.put(b, k.get(b) + 1);
            }
            else {
                k.put(b, 1f);
            }
        }

        for (char b : input.toCharArray()) {
            float freq = k.get(b) / input.length();
            result.setText(getString(b) + " " + freq);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greetingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/greeting_message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.109" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
        android:onClick="onClickFindRelevancy"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="191dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/continueButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/greetingText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="205dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="418dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="206dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="294dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.<theprogrammnameihave>">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error I get when the app stops working -

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kriptoprogramma, PID: 13645
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x54
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:432)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:556)
        at com.example.kriptoprogramma.MainActivity.onClickFindRelevancy(MainActivity.java:36)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: You should add the error stack trace in the question.

Comment: In Android Studio, open the Run tab below. You can see your stack trace there.

Comment: the error stack trace usually tells you what is wrong or at least where to look

Comment: @EraftYps Sorry, I forgot about it. It is added now. So from error information there is something wrong with onClick, but I don't really know why, because I have added the method that should be executed when the button is clicked...

Comment: From the stack trace: `at ... MainActivity.onClickFindRelevancy(MainActivity.java:36)` <- the problem is on line 36 of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use error stack trace, as suggested in comments. See [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

The mistake is that you use `getString` method to convert a `char` to `String`.
In Android, this is the method of `Activity` (and `Context`) to get a string from resources (i. e. when you are localizing your app).

You should use `String.valueOf(char)` instead.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you said, but when I try to put String.valueOf(char) in the place of getString(b), I am not able to concatinate String.valueOf(char) with a space and the freq variable.

Comment: I mean String.valueOf(b).